# How do I select the last row of a MySQL table with Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am writing something for my friend that will involve storing some data in a database with a primary key which is an integer which will increment. For example:

```
id    name      Age

1     James     15
2     Max       24
3     Jordan    61
```

How would I retrieve the integer under the id column in the last row? And this would be with Java. Thanks.

Comment: Typically users on Stack Overflow are required to provide a sample of what they have tried already.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have not tried anything seeing that I have never known how do to something like this.

Answer (score 2):

If the "last" row is the one with the highest ID, your SQL (to retrieve just the ID, like you asked) will look like:

```
SELECT id FROM User ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

In Java, you'll probably be using JDBC; best practice is to learn how to use [`PreparedStatement`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Do not use prepared statements just for one query.

Comment: Why not? I realize that this particular query isn't a potential vector for injection attacks, but I'd guess that `getMostRecentUser()` (or wherever this query would show up) would be called with some frequency.

Answer (score 0):

is it like

`id name age`

```
1 james 15
2 max 24
3 jordan 61
```

PRIMARY KEY(id)

```
 SELECT id

FROM `tablename`

ORDER BY id DESC 

LIMIT 0 , 1
```

this will return the last row id result set from ur table